# How to calculate mode when using python-polars in aggregation

Tags: python, aggregation, python-polars, statistical-mode

I am involving in a data-mining project and have some problems whiling doing feature engineering. One of my goal is to aggregate data according to the primary key, and to produce new columns. So I write this:

```
df = df.group_by("case_id").agg(date_exprs(df,df_base))

def date_expr(df, df_base):
    # Join df and df_base on 'case_id' column
    df = df.join(df_base[['case_id','date_decision']], on="case_id", how="left")

    for col in df.columns:
        if col[-1] in ("D",):
            df = df.with_columns(pl.col(col) - pl.col("date_decision"))
            df = df.with_columns(pl.col(col).dt.total_days())

    cols = [col for col in df.columns if col[-1] in ("D",)]

    # Generate expressions for max, min, mean, mode, and std of date differences
    expr_max = [pl.max(col).alias(f"max_{col}") for col in cols]
    expr_min = [pl.min(col).alias(f"min_{col}") for col in cols]
    expr_mean = [pl.mean(col).alias(f"mean_{col}") for col in cols]
    expr_mode = [pl.mode(col).alias(f"mode_{col}") for col in cols]
    expr_std = [pl.std(col).alias(f"std_{col}") for col in cols]

    return expr_max + expr_min + expr_mean + expr_mode + expr_std
```

However, there goes an error: AttributeError: module 'polars' has no attribute 'mode'.

I looked up document of polars on github and found there was no Dataframe.mode() but Series.mode(), which I thought might be the reason of error? I referred to chatGPT, which could not help because these codes with error were just from it.

Besides, here is only an example of dealing with float type. What about string type? Can I also apply your method?

I am looking forward to your kind help!!

Comment: From the docs, it seems like something like `pl.col(col).mode()` would work. Can you try that?

Comment: Thank you! Using 'pl.col(col).mode()' can help me get a list for each case_id and each column. Then maybe I can transfer list to number and I can get what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example it fails because there's no syntactic sugar for [`Expr.mode()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.mode.html) as it is for aggregate functions (for example, [`pl.max()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.max.html) is a syntactic sugar for [`Expr.max()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.max.html). The `mode()` is actually not aggregation function but computation one, which means it just calculates the most occuring value(s) within the column.

So, given the DataFrame like this:

```py
df = (
    pl.DataFrame({
        'aD' : [200, 200, 300, 400, 1, 3],
        'bD': [2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 1],
        'case_id': [1,1,1,2,2,2]
    })
)

┌─────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ aD  ┆ bD  ┆ case_id │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ 200 ┆ 2   ┆ 1       │
│ 200 ┆ 3   ┆ 1       │
│ 300 ┆ 6   ┆ 1       │
│ 400 ┆ 4   ┆ 2       │
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 2       │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 2       │
└─────┴─────┴─────────┘
```

you can calculate `mode()` with the following code:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('aD').mode(),
    pl.col('bD').mode()
)

┌─────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ aD  ┆ bD  ┆ case_id │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ 200 ┆ 1   ┆ 1       │
│ 200 ┆ 5   ┆ 1       │
│ 200 ┆ 6   ┆ 1       │
│ 200 ┆ 4   ┆ 2       │
│ 200 ┆ 2   ┆ 2       │
│ 200 ┆ 3   ┆ 2       │
└─────┴─────┴─────────┘
```

given that, we still can calculate the results you need. I'll simplify you function a bit by using [`selectors`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html) and [`Expr.prefix()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.prefix.html):

```py
import polars.selectors as cs

def date_expr():
    # Generate expressions for max, min, mean, mode, and std of date differences
    expr_max = cs.ends_with('D').max().name.prefix("max_")
    expr_min = cs.ends_with('D').min().name.prefix("min_")
    expr_mean = cs.ends_with('D').mean().name.prefix("mean_")
    expr_mode = cs.ends_with('D').mode().first().name.prefix("mode_")
    expr_std = cs.ends_with('D').std().name.prefix("std_")

    return expr_max, expr_min, expr_mean, expr_std, expr_mode

df.group_by("case_id").agg(date_expr())

┌─────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬───┬────────────┬──────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ case_id ┆ max_aD ┆ max_bD ┆ min_aD ┆ … ┆ std_aD     ┆ std_bD   ┆ mode_aD ┆ mode_bD │
│ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆   ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64    ┆   ┆ f64        ┆ f64      ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪════════╪════════╪════════╪═══╪════════════╪══════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 2       ┆ 400    ┆ 5      ┆ 1      ┆ … ┆ 229.787583 ┆ 2.081666 ┆ 3       ┆ 4       │
│ 1       ┆ 300    ┆ 6      ┆ 200    ┆ … ┆ 57.735027  ┆ 2.081666 ┆ 200     ┆ 2       │
└─────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴───┴────────────┴──────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

note that I've used [`Expr.first()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.first.html) to the one of the values for `mode` - as there might be different ones with the same frequency. You can use `list` expressions to specify which one you'd like to get.

Comment: **Note.** Using `expr.mode().first()` will be non-deterministic as the order of the modes return by `expr.mode()` may change between evaluations. If this is problematic, one could use `expr.mode().sort().first()` to pick the smallest mode.

Comment: Thanks for the note, it's correct indeed. I just realized I was not entirely correct about using `list` methods to get desirable value - it's easier to just use `expr` ones to avoid aggregations.